# Web Scraping based on Query Terms from Thesaurus.com

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to scrape all the synonyms from *www.thesaurus.com* when a user enters any word (see picture).

I've been successful getting the info such as "noun" and "meaning", but when it comes to trying to get the synonyms, I run into an issue because each "value" of the

```
BeautifulSoup .find_all('a', attrs={'href':'**my problem**'})
```

is going to be different since `href = "/browse/**each different synonym**"`.

My intention is to gather all the highlighted words in the picture like "capability" and "capacity" etc. [image: search term: power]
**inspect html code**
[image: inspect html code]

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow; please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it easier to `.select()` by CSS selector, see below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/power")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# select only first '<section class="synonyms-container....'
synonyms = soup.select('.MainContentContainer > section > .synonyms-container a')
print 'synonyms for: Power'
for synonym in synonyms:
    print synonym.text
    #print synonym.get('href')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to laugh since it did exactly what I wanted after spending hours on this (I'm fairly new to coding). Much appreciated!